# view id after inflating

Tags: android

I created an LinearLayout using the following code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_item, null);
```

My question is, is container.getId() equal to 'R.layout.my_item' after the code above is executed? Or, do I have to set id to the newly created layout using the code below?

```
container.setId(R.layout.my_item);
```

My example code showed that I have to explicitly set id to the layout created from code, which is out of my expectation.

Thanks.

Edit:
The purpose that I want to set id on the layout is for OnClick listener set on the layout.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent;

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.layout.my_item:
      ....
    break;
```

Comment: why are you doing a container.setId(R.layout.my_item) ?? R.layout does hold the id created on R but for layout?? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I edited my question. The purpose is for OnClick listener set on the layout.

Comment: So you want to attach an OnClick listener to a number of different items?

Comment: Yes. But I will set different tag values to different items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The id would be the id of the view you inflated. That is to say, whatever the `android:id` of the root element of `R.layout.my_item` is. It should be an R.id value, not a R.layout one.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [on Android developers website](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId%28%29).